# Check if the position if less then or greater then another position prolog

Tags: prolog, shortest-path

I have revised this question to be more specific on what I'm looking for. I am trying to find if the position of (1,2) is greater than (1,1). Using the following code I get a specific element, being **what**, and return the position. For example if we want to find 1 in this maze, than we do the following:

```
findMaze([Row|_],What,(0,C)):-
   findRow(Row,What,C).
findMaze([_|Rows],What,R):-
   findMaze(Rows,What,TempR),
   R is TempR + 1.

findRow([What|_],What,0).
findRow([_|Tail],What,Where):-
   findRow(Tail,What,TWhere),
   Where is TWhere + 1.
```

Now all I want to do is take (1,1) and compare it with (1,2) to see if that is greater than (1,1). Ultimately what I want to accomplish is find the left and right of a position. So the left of (1,1) would be (1,0) and (1,2) would be the right. How do I make these into paths, thus getting the shortest path from (1,1) to (1,3).

Comment: @DanielLyons  how would you check if there is a - or x next to the piece on the board?

Comment: @DanielLyons no it doesnt. I have edited the question to show what I'm talking about.

Comment: @DanielLyons Sure! findMaze([[x,x,x,x,x,x,x],[x,-,-,-,-,-,1,x]],1,What).                 What = (2,6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question:

```
mazeCell(Maze, What, (X,Y)) :-
    nth1(X, Maze, Row),
    nth0(Y, Row, What).
```

This captures the behavior you want:

```
?- mazeCell([[x,x,x,x,x,x,x],[x,-,-,-,-,-,1,x]], 1, Point).
Point =  (2, 6)
```

I note that mixing `nth1` and `nth0` like this is not supremely intuitive, and I do wonder if you are confusing your X and Y coordinates, but ultimately it probably shouldn't matter.

The nice thing about this predicate is that it is very versatile; you can use it to look things up by index, search for things by value, or iterate the entire maze. So for instance, you can examine the neighboring cells like this:

```
pointNeighbor((X,Y), (X1,Y)) :- succ(X, X1).
pointNeighbor((X,Y), (X1,Y)) :- succ(X1, X).
pointNeighbor((X,Y), (X,Y1)) :- succ(Y, Y1).
pointNeighbor((X,Y), (X,Y1)) :- succ(Y1, Y).

neighbors(Maze, Point, NeighborPoint, NeighborValue) :-
    pointNeighbor(Point, NeighborPoint),
    mazeCell(Maze, NeighborValue, NeighborPoint).
```

Now we can find the cells next to the player quite easily:

```
?- Maze = [[x,x,x,x,x,x,x],[x,-,-,-,-,-,1,x]], 
   mazeCell(Maze, 1, Point), 
   neighbors(Maze, Point, NeighborPoint, NeighborValue).
Maze = [[x, x, x, x, x, x, x], [x, -, -, -, -, -, 1|...]],
Point =  (2, 6),
NeighborPoint =  (1, 6),
NeighborValue = x ;

Maze = [[x, x, x, x, x, x, x], [x, -, -, -, -, -, 1|...]],
Point =  (2, 6),
NeighborPoint =  (2, 7),
NeighborValue = x ;

Maze = [[x, x, x, x, x, x, x], [x, -, -, -, -, -, 1|...]],
Point =  (2, 6),
NeighborPoint =  (2, 5),
NeighborValue =  (-) ;

false.
```

Notice that we didn't worry about whether we were generating valid points; `mazeCell` will simply fail if you ask for points that don't exist. We also didn't have to worry about traversing the maze other ways. `mazeCell/3` is general enough to handle whatever. And now we have the interesting points and the interesting values at once and can do whatever we wish with them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it does thanks for all your help man. It's been well appreciated

Comment: Glad I was able to help you in the end!

Comment: I forgot to ask one thing about this, say I'm trying to define an edge for every element up until a certain point how would you do something with the above?

Comment: Not sure I understand you.

Comment: Basically I want to iterate through the maze at position (1,4), for example, and stick (1,3)-(1,1) into a list and stop at (1,0) because an element has been found.

Comment: I'm still having trouble seeing what you're asking, maybe you should post a new question and someone else will be able to help you.