# Generate all permutation of N (N - given) respecting the property: for every 2<=i<=n exists a 1<=j<=i, so |v(i)-v(j)|=1 in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Generate all permutation of N (N - given) respecting the property: for every 2<=i<=n exists a 1<=j<=i,
so |v(i)-v(j)|=1. I have found a solution building the list of the first N numbers(it is built reversed), reversing it, testing for every number if the condition is met, applying that for every number on a possible permutation found using the candidate predicate. Here is the code that works so far:

```
% candidate returns each number from the list and the list without it
% candidate(L - list, R - integer, L1 - list)
% flow(i,o,o)
% candidate(l1...ln)= - l1,l2...ln
%                     - (e,l1 U L), (e,L) = candidate(l2...ln)

candidate([H|T],H,T).
candidate([H|T],R,[H|T1]):-candidate(T,R,T1).

%build(N - integer, L - list)
%flow(i,o)
%build(l1...ln,n) = - [], n = 0 or 1
%                   - build(l2...ln,n-1), n>1

build(0,[]).
build(1,[]).
build(N1,[N|L]) :- N1 > 1, N is N1 - 1, build(N,L).

%reverse(L - input list, Z - list, R - list)
%flow(i,o,i)
%reverse(l1...ln) = - [], list is empty
%                   - l1 U reverse(l2...ln)
reverse([],Z,Z).
reverse([H|T],Z,Acc) :- reverse(T,Z,[H|Acc]).

%buildReverse(N - integer, R - list)
%flow(i,o)
buildReverse(N1,R):-build(N1+1,R1),reverse(R1,R,[]).

%checks whether the condition in the requirement
%nrTest(L - list, R - int, I - int)
%nrTest(i,i,o)
%nrTest(l1...ln,r,i) = - false, l1 = r, i = 1
%                      - true, abs(l1-r)= 1, list length is 1
%                      - true, abs(l1-r)= 1
%                      - nrTest(l2...ln,r,1)
%                      - nrTest(l2...ln,r,1), i = 0, l1 = r
nrTest([],0,_).
nrTest([R|T],R,0):-nrTest(T,R,1).
nrTest([R|_T],R,1):-!,fail.
nrTest([H],R,_):-1 is abs(H-R),true,!.
nrTest([H|_T],R,_):-1 is abs(H-R),true,!.
nrTest([_H|T],R,_I):-nrTest(T,R,1).

% checks if for every element of the list the condition in the
% requirement is met
% test2(L - list, R - list)
% flow(i,i)
% test2(l1...ln,r1...rn) = - false, lists are empty
%                          - true, first list is empty
%                          - true, lists have one element each
%                          - test2(l2...ln,r1...rn), if
%                          nrTest(r1...rn,l1,0)
test2([],[]):-false.
test2([],_):-true.
test2([_],[_]):-true.
test2([H|T],R):-nrTest(R,H,0),test2(T,R),!.

%wrapper for test2
%test2Wrap(R - list)
%flow(i)
test2Wrap([]):-false.
test2Wrap([_]):-true.
test2Wrap(R):-test2(R,R).

%perm2(L - list, R - list)
%flow(i,o)
%perm2(l1...ln,r1...rn) = - [], list is empty
%                         - perm2(candidate(l1...ln,r1),r2...rn),
%                         otherwise
perm2([],[]).
perm2(L,[E|T]):-candidate(L,E,R),perm2(R,T).

%perm3(L - list, R - list)
%flow(i,o)
%perm3(l1...ln,r1...rn) = - perm3(l1...ln,r1...rn), test2Wrap(r1...rn)
perm3(L,R):-perm2(L,R),test2Wrap(R).

%wrapper(N - int, R - list)
%flow(i,o)
wrapper(0,[]).
wrapper(N,R):-buildReverse(N,R1),perm3(R1,R).
```

I am curious to see if there are any simpler methods for doing that, as it seems I've complicated it more than I should have.

Comment: Which predicate in your code is the "main thing" that you're trying to do, the permutation generator?

Comment: @DanielLyons perm2 does that using the predicate candidate. perm3 just takes them and verifies if the condition is met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's compare to the SWI-Prolog implementation of [`permutation/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=permutation/2) (click the `:-` button to [see the source](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#permutation/2). There's a bunch of type checking and then it resolves to a call to this predicate:

```
perm([], []).
perm(List, [First|Perm]) :-
    select(First, List, Rest),
    perm(Rest, Perm).
```

This doesn't look much different from yours; let's see if [`select/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#select/3) and `candidate/3` are comparable:

```
select(X, [Head|Tail], Rest) :-
   select3_(Tail, Head, X, Rest).

select3_(Tail, Head, Head, Tail).
select3_([Head2|Tail], Head, X, [Head|Rest]) :-
    select3_(Tail, Head2, X, Rest).
```

So the documentation suggests that the use of `select3_/3` here is really about making the predicate deterministic on the last element. Indeed, this is a small distinction between `candidate/3` and `select/3`, apart from the order of parameters:

```
?- candidate([a,b,c], X, Y).
X = a,
Y = [b, c] ;
X = b,
Y = [a, c] ;
X = c,
Y = [a, b] ;
false.

?- select(X, [a,b,c], Y).
X = a,
Y = [b, c] ;
X = b,
Y = [a, c] ;
X = c,
Y = [a, b].
```

No trailing `false` here.

There is a build-in `reverse/2`, so there's no need for you to code that. There is not a built-in predicate to give you lists of length N of integers. I would have coded that slightly differently without using `reverse/2`, like this:

```
iota(N, L) :- iota(1, N, L).

iota(N, N, [N]).
iota(N0, N, [N0|NL]) :- 
    N0 < N, 
    succ(N0, N1), 
    iota(N1, N, NL).
```

Past this, we get into your `wrapper/2`, `perm3/2`, `test2/2`, `nrTest/3` predicates, and I don't really understand what you're trying to do there. But I don't think there's anything intrinsically terrible about your permutation generator, you just need to utilize the library routines where they exist (remove `candidate/3` and use `select/3`, use the supplied `reverse/2` if really necessary).

Prolog is very high level, but it is not very terse. Prolog code of excellent quality *can* be shorter than comparable procedural code, but (in my experience) this has to do with the variety of calling conventions available to you and relational thinking, because the language by itself just isn't that short. [I wrote about this on my blog](http://www.storytotell.org/post/prologs-advantage/) with an example from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34033215/check-if-the-position-if-less-then-or-greater-then-another-position-prolog/34059544#34059544).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, @DanielLyons. From what I understand, the idea and approach are pretty much ok, except for the predicate for generating the list of length N of integers. I actually wrote the reverse just because the teacher asked us not to use any built-in predicates. As for the other ones, `nrTest/3` just checks if, for a given number, there is one before it in the list that has a difference of 1. `test2/2` applies that to all the numbers in a given list, `perm3/2` takes all permutations from `perm2/2` and tests that condition on them. `wrapper/2` is only for running.